# How to Http post to django server from android?

Tags: android, django, forms, http-post

I am trying to send post request to my django APi from but It does not give any error it works fine but still django does not recieve any data. 
My view goes like this.

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = bookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.save()
            return redirect('/books')
    else:
        form = bookForm
return render(request, 'book_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

And my Http post method is.

```
try{
                Log.w("this","Started");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new  HttpPost("http://vidu171.pythonanywhere.com/books/add");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", params[0]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("author","vidu"));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.w("htt response",response.toString());
 }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

            }
```

I have given the permission the url to the form is
http://vidu171.pythonanywhere.com/books/add . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that for making API calls in Django from other sources like Android Apps, its better to use Rest APIs, in case of Django, try using Django Rest Framework.You can start by this [Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)

Comment: I made the APi like that But i don't know how to post to the API from ANdroid.

Comment: Try re-implementing your API using the Rest Framework.

Comment: then how will i post from android?

Comment: For Android Specific code, I would suggest you have a look at this [link](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64)